# Group list by equivalence relation

Tags: list, haskell

I have a [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) `R` on a set `A`. How can I build equivalence classes on `A`? It's something like `groupBy` do, but between all the elements, not only neighbors.

For example, `equal` is equivalence relation (it is reflexive, symmetric and transitive binary relation):

```
type Sometuple = (Int, Int, Int)

equal :: Sometuple -> Sometuple -> Bool
equal (_, x, _) (_, y, _) = x == y
```

It is actually a predicate that connect 2 `Sometuple` elements.

```
λ> equal (1,2,3) (1,2,2)
True
```

So, how can I build all equivalence classes on `[Sometuple]` based on `equal` predicate? Something like that:

```
equivalenceClasses :: (Sometuple -> Sometuple -> Bool) -> [Sometuple] -> [[Sometuple]]
λ> equivalenceClasses equal [(1,2,3), (2,1,4), (0,3,2), (9,2,1), (5,3,1), (1,3,1)]
[[(1,2,3),(9,2,1)],[(2,1,4)],[(0,3,2),(5,3,1),(1,3,2)]]
```

Comment: You may find this package useful. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/equivalence

Comment: The `equivalence` package requires some mutable monadic context (`IO` or `ST`).  Try `persistent-equivalence` instead for something a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you can define a compatible ordering relation, you can use

```
equivalenceClasses equal comp = groupBy equal . sortBy comp
```

which would give you `O(n*log n)` complexity. Without that, I don't see any way to get better complexity than `O(n^2)`, basically

```
splitOffFirstGroup :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
splitOffFirstGroup equal xs@(x:_) = partition (equal x) xs
splitOffFirstGroup _     []       = ([],[])

equivalenceClasses _     [] = []
equivalenceClasses equal xs = let (fg,rst) = splitOffFirstGroup equal xs
                              in fg : equivalenceClasses equal rst
```

Comment: I would call this algorithm *O(nm)*, where `n` is the size of the list, and `m` is the number of distinct equivalence classes represented by the list. The worst case, of course, would be `m = n`, meaning a *O(n^2)* algorithm, but the best case would be `m = 1`, meaning a *O(n)* algorithm.

Comment: 1) How can comparator helps out in that case. There is no way to range all set elements in order, that all elements from the single equivalent class will be neighbors.

2) Why `O(n^2)` is a better complexity>

Comment: @dmitry.malikov 1) With a compatible ordering, that means, one such that `cmp x y == EQ` if and only if `equal x y`, you can sort the list in `O(n*log n)` time, then all equivalent items are contiguous and the list can be grouped in `O(n)`. For your example above, a compatible ordering would be `cmp (_,x,_) (_,y,_) = compare x y`, but in general it would be hard to define.

Comment: 2) As Dan Burton clarified, `O(n^2)` is the _worst case_ complexity. If no two items are equivalent, it would run through all `n` elements to identify the first equivalence class, then through the remaining `n-1` elements to identify the second equivalence class etc, altogether it would take `n + (n-1) + ... + 1 = n*(n+1)/2` steps. If you're lucky, there are only few equivalence classes and the algorithm would require only `O(n)` steps. But if you only have the equivalence relation, and no two elements are equivalent, you have to test every item against all others, giving `O(n^2)` complexity.

Answer (score 3):

The correct data structure to use here is a [**disjoint set**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) (Tarjan).  A purely functional, persistent implementation of such a structure was described by [Conchon and Filliâtre](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.79.8494).  There's an implementation [on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-equivalence).

Comment: Can you explain how you can use a disjoint set structure to get a better algorithm than Daniel Fischer's? I don't see how.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight variation of Daniel's suggestion:

Since equivalence classes partition a set of values (meaning that every value belongs to exactly one class), you can use a value to represent its class. In many cases, however, it is quite natural to choose one canonical representative per class. In your example, you might go for `(0,x,0)` representing the class `{ (0,0,0), (0,0,1), (1,0,0), (1,0,1), (2,0,0), ... }`. You can therefore define a representative function as follows:

```
representative :: Sometuple -> Sometuple
representative (_,x,_) = (0,x,0)
```

Now, by definition, `equal a b` is the same as `(representative a) == (representative b)`. So if you sort a list of values by representative -- assuming we're dealing with members of `Ord` --, members of the same equivalence class end up next to each other and can be grouped by ordinary `groupBy`.

The function you were looking for thus becomes:

```
equivalenceClasses :: Ord a => (a -> a) -> [a] -> [[a]]
equivalenceClasses rep = groupBy ((==) `on` rep) . sortBy (compare `on` rep)
```

Daniel's suggestion is a generalisation of this approach. I'm essentially proposing a specific ordering relation (namely comparison by representative) that can be derived easily in many use cases.

Caveat 1: You need to make sure that representatives of the same/different equivalence classes are actually equal/different according to `(==)` and `compare`. If those two functions test for structural equality, this is always the case.

Caveat 2: Technically, you can relax the type of `equivalenceClasses` to

```
equivalenceClasses :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have noted that the problem is hard to do efficiently without some extra structure on the equivalence relation. If one recalls definitions from mathematics, an equivalence relation is equivalent to a quotient map (ie a function from your set to the equivalence classes). We can write a Haskell function which, given the quotient map (or rather something isomorphic to it) and some nice properties of it’s codomain, groups by the equivalence relation. We can also define equivalence based on quotient maps.

```
import Data.Map

group :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
group q xs = elems $ fromListWith (++) [(q x, [x]) | x <- xs]

sameClass :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> (a -> a -> Bool)
sameClass q a b = q a == q b

-- for your question
equal = sameClass (\(_,x,_) -> x)
group (\(_,x,_) -> x) [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

This following solution performs a little faster than Daniel Fischer's on small data *(lists shorter than about 2¹⁴ = 16384 elements)*. It works by adding elements to equivalence classes one by one, creating a new class if an element does not belong to any of the existing ones.

```
module Classify where

import qualified Data.List as List

classify :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]
classify = classifyBy (==)

classifyBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
classifyBy eq = List.foldl' f [ ]
  where
    f [ ] y = [[y]]
    f (xs@ (x: _): xss) y | x `eq` y  = (y: xs): xss
                          | otherwise = xs: f xss y
```

Answer (score 0):

[Turns out there is a similar function in `GHC.Exts`.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#v:groupWith)

```
λ import GHC.Exts
λ groupWith snd [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
[[('a',1),('c',1)],[('b',2)]]
```

It requires you to define a function from your type to a type with a compatible
`Ord` which `Eq` coincides with your notion of equivalence. *(`snd` here.)* Categorially, you
may see this function as an arrow onto the set of equivalence classes, also called a quotient map.

[Thanks to Olaf for pointing out.](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2020-December/133241.html)

Comment: some elementary example for such "arrow" would help clarify its meaning.

Comment: @WillNess Well, `snd`?

Comment: ah, okay. _________